# Can a batsman be run out on a boundary shot?

Tags: rules, cricket

Suppose a batsman hits the ball. The boundary fielder picks it up, but his leg touched the boundary rope.

The fielder throws the ball and one of the players is out of the crease when the wicket is broken.

Is the batsman run out or not ?

Comment: @Nij - I've removed "catches" from the question as that adds a second level of complexity here around when the catch is completed - if the catch is completed before the fielder steps on the rope, then the batsman is out anyway.

Comment: Catching a ball is not the same as catching a ball *on the full directly from the bat*. A fielder cannot pick up a ball if it is in the air from bouncing, but that situation is identical to this one otherwise. I strongly suggest that you rollback, and then edit further if clarifying the sense of "caught" is required. @PhilipKendall

Comment: "Caught" is a term with a very common meaning in cricket; using it to mean "caught on the bounce" is just confusing. I suggest we leave it to the OP to edit as they desire if they don't like the question as is.

Comment: Perhaps "... collects the ball" then, to cover any case of a fielder taking control of it, since the *how* is a minor detail compared to the fact they're standing on the boundary.

Answer (score 5):

No. As soon as the fielder was simultaneously in contact with both the ball and the boundary rope, the boundary is scored and the ball is dead. See [Law 23.1](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-23-dead-ball/):

> The ball becomes dead when [...] a boundary is scored. See Law 19.3 (Scoring a boundary).

The relevant part of [Law 19.3](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-19-boundaries/) is

> A boundary shall be scored and signalled by the bowler’s end umpire whenever [...] a fielder with some part of his person in contact with the ball, touches the boundary

Answer (score -2):

As per the law of cricket, if a fielder body part or any of his/her accessories(like cap,hat) touches the rope at the time of collecting/catching the ball,it is considered as boundary and ball become dead until the next action resume.

Comment: This is true but adds nothing at all to my answer.

Comment: Absolutely, there is nothing wrong in your answer but i just wanted to add a scenario when players cap or other accessories topples and touches the rope then another level of complexity may arise which will go in batsman favor.

Comment: Chandan, at least to me, it does seem a good point to add to Philip's answer.  However, that's what comments are more designed for, as they keep it much clearer than a whole separate answer.  Unfortunately, you won't be able to comment on other answers until you get to 50 reputation :-/.  Perhaps @PhilipKendall can add the information in (if he views it as correct and useful to the overall completeness of the answer), and then you or a moderator can delete this whole answer.  And soon enough you'll have your 50 points, and will be able to comment :-)